# With Reportgrid as graphing library how to show images instead of shapes at data points for line graph

Tags: javascript, graph

I am using reportgrid js charting/graphing tool to display graphs, the problem is I instead of showing nodes I want to show images, is there anyway? or shall I use some other library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That option is currently under development and it is already available for the Sankey. For the other charts that support symbols it should be available by the end of this week.

In the meanwhile, there are ways to work around the issue by using JQuery (or another library) to select the corresponding symbol nodes and replace them with an image node.

Unfortunately SVG doesn't support background images that would make the feat trivial.

Comment: The feature is officially out. To enable it you have 2 options for the  already existing parameter "symbol".
1. symbol : "image:http://example.com/image.jpg"
2. symbol : function(datapoint, stats) { return /* compute the above string individually for each datapoint */; }